# NFC Android: getting value from a NdefMessage

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm messing around with some tags (Mifare classic)

I have written with the nxp application tagwriter an message in plaintext to the tag.

the following code is what I have so far:

```
 ** Called when a new nfc interaction/intent is fired */
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    if(intent.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)){
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if(rawMsgs!=null){
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for(int i=0;i<rawMsgs.length;i++){
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Other intent then NDEF_DISCOVERED");
    }
```

I dont know where to go one from this point, can someone point me in the right direction?

I want to read the value inside these messages, I already know that a ndefmessage contains ndefrecords, but how can i determine which record is the record i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example for the first record of the first message:

```
NdefRecord[] recs = msgs[0].getRecords();
byte[] type = recs[0].getType();
byte[] value = recs[0].getPayload();
```

When you know the type, you may be able to interpret the `value` bytes.

Answer (score -1):

The Android built-in SDK does currently barely support parsing NDEF messages and records.

I have written an [Eclipse plugin](http://nfc-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com) for getting started with NFC (NDEF) on Android, it is based on [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools), which can read and write various NDEF records like the above NdefMessage - so you will see POJOs instead of byte arrays :-)

Also try the [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/).

Comment: Note that the question implies that the poster has already written the message. The poster is interested in reading and parsing the message from the tag.

Comment: I do not share that interpretation about the poster, but even if I did, the tools I am referring do READ and WRITE both NDEF messages, records on a byte level and parses records into POJOs - which is obviously very desirable. So if your current answer is the best you can do, check out those links.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but the Android code at your link, e.g. at http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/source/browse/Android%20NFC/src/com/antares/nfc/client/NfcReaderActivity.java I don't even see the level of detail that my answer provides (which is limited, I agree). I have seen to many apps already that write improperly formatted NDEF messages, unfortunately. If the project your link points at can help improve this situation (or will be able to in the future), I would love to see that, as I think that is very valuable.

Comment: Good point, I will update the boilerplate with more detail. However I was thinking of the nfctools [https://github.com/grundid/nfctools/tree/master/nfctools-ndef/src/main/java/org/nfctools/ndef/](ndef) ndef section for more details (POJOs).

Comment: Ah, there are 2 links, I missed that. Sorry. Yes, showing how to use the nfctools in an Android app would be a valuable addition.